# Pygame displays black screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to write a simple sokoban game in python 3.5 using Pygame, however when I run the code I just get a black background. I'm sure I'm just doing something wrong with the blit but still learning so not too sure.
Any help anyone can give would be greatly appreciated :)

```
import random, pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

from Classes import Maze, Move, Player, Box

maze = Maze()

WHITE = (255, 255, 255) 

FPS = 30
WINWIDTH = 750
WINHEIGHT = 750
HALFHEIGHT = int(WINWIDTH/2)
HALFWIDTH = int(WINWIDTH/2)
#BASICFONT = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.tff',100)

#Tile height and width in pixels
TILEWIDTH = 30
TILEHEIGHT = 30
TILEFLOORHEIGHT = 30

IMAGESDICT = {"WALL": pygame.image.load("C:/Users/Trail/Documents/College 2/Object Oriented Programming/Sokoban Implement/images/wall.bmp"),
          "FLOOR": pygame.image.load(""C:/Users/Trail/Documents/College 2/Object Oriented Programming/Sokoban Implement/images/floor.bmp"),
          "CRATE": pygame.image.load(""C:/Users/Trail/Documents/College 2/Object Oriented Programming/Sokoban Implement/images/object.bmp"),
          "TARGET": pygame.image.load("C:/Users/Trail/Documents/College 2/Object Oriented Programming/Sokoban Implement/images/wall.bmp"object_store),
          "PLAYER": pygame.image.load("C:/Users/Trail/Documents/College 2/Object Oriented Programming/Sokoban Implement/images/mover_left.bmp")}

TILEMAPPING = {"#":IMAGESDICT["WALL"],
           " ":IMAGESDICT["FLOOR"],
           "$":IMAGESDICT["CRATE"],
           "@":IMAGESDICT["TARGET"],
           "P":IMAGESDICT["PLAYER"]}


#Display surface
pygame.init()
FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
DISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode((WINWIDTH,WINHEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Sokoban")

def Build(maze):

maze.walls(10)
maze.targets(5)
maze.startPos()

mapSurfWidth = maze.getWidth() * TILEWIDTH
mapSurfHeight = maze.getHeight() * TILEHEIGHT
mapSurf = pygame.Surface((mapSurfWidth,mapSurfHeight))
mapSurf.fill(WHITE)

for h in range(maze.getHeight()):
    for w in range(maze.getWidth()):
        tile = pygame.Rect((w * TILEWIDTH, h * TILEFLOORHEIGHT, TILEWIDTH, TILEHEIGHT))
        if maze.getPos(h,w) in TILEMAPPING:
            baseTile = TILEMAPPING[maze.getPos(h,w)]

        #Draw
        mapSurf.blit(baseTile,tile)

return mapSurf

def main():
Build(maze)

main()
```

And my Maze class (This is indented in my code but not here for formatting):

```
class Maze:
def __init__(self):
    self.width = 20
    self.height = 10

    #init
    width = 20
    height = 10
    #Create 2D array for maze
    self.maze = [[0 for i in range(width)] for j in range(height)]

    #Create square grid
    for i in range(width):
        for j in range(height):
            if j == 0 or j == height - 1:
                self.maze[j][i] = "#"
            elif i == 0 or i == width - 1:
                self.maze[j][i] = "#"
            else:
                self.maze[j][i] = " "

def crates(self,level):
    self.level = level

    for i in range(0,level):
        #Don't spawn here if wall is already generated
        if self.maze[i+2][i+5] == "#":
            self.maze[i+3][i+6] = "$"
        else:
            self.maze[i+2][i+5] = "$"
    return self.maze

def walls(self,level):
    self.level = level

    #Semi working, needs randomised for play
    for i in range(0,level):
        for j in range(0,level):
            #Shitty random gen
            y = level / 2
            x = randint(0,level)
            y = randint(0,y)

            #Shitty test random wall gen
            if x % 3 == 0:
                self.maze[y][x] = "#"

            """if (j % 3 == 0) and (i < 4):
                self.maze[j][i] = "#"
            elif (j % 2 == 0) and (i > 8):
                self.maze[i][j] = "#"""
    return self.maze

def targets(self,level):
    self.level = level

    #Test
    for i in range(0,level):
        self.maze[i+2][i+10] = "@"
    return self.maze

def startPos(self):

    x = randint(1,5)
    y = randint(1,5)

    self.maze[x][y] = "P"
    return self.maze

def getWidth(self):
    return self.width

def getHeight(self):
    return self.height

def getPos(self,row,col):
    return self.maze[row][col]
```

Comment: do you have a `while` loop somewhere? did you remember to call `pygame.display.update()` or `pygame.display.flip()`?

Comment: also there is a typo in `IMAGEDICT["FLOOR"]` and `IMAGEDICT["CRATE"]`

Comment: Ah thank you, I had missed the pygame.display.update(), that's it working properly!